# Get the last entry in database of two different dates and calculate the difference

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that records information from an inverter roughly every 15 minutes.  One of the pieces of data that the inverter sends is the `kwhtotal` which is a number that represents how much total power has been generated through that inverter.  I am trying to get the query right for getting the power generated for a particular day.  To do that I need to retrieve the last reading on the prior day and compare it to the last reading on the current day.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DateTime prevStartD = new DateTime((utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Year, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Month, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Day, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime prevEndD = new DateTime((utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Year, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Month, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i - 1)).Day, 23, 59, 59);

var previousDay = (from s in db.PowerInverterHistorys
                   join u in db.PowerInverters on s.inverter_id equals u.id
                   where u.name == record && (s.recordTime >= prevStartD && s.recordTime <= prevEndD)
                   orderby s.recordTime descending
                   select new
                   {
                       s.recordTime,
                       s.kwhtotal
                   }).Take(1);

DateTime currStartD = new DateTime((utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Year, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Month, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Day, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime currEndD = new DateTime((utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Year, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Month, (utcStartingDate.AddDays(i)).Day, 23, 59, 59);

var currentDay = (from s in db.PowerInverterHistorys
                  join u in db.PowerInverters on s.inverter_id equals u.id
                  where u.name == record && (s.recordTime >= currStartD && s.recordTime <= currEndD)
                  orderby s.recordTime descending
                  select new
                  {
                      s.recordTime,
                      s.kwhtotal
                  }).Take(1);

double? pDay = 0, cDay = 0;
foreach (var p in previousDay) { pDay = p.kwhtotal; }
foreach (var c in currentDay) { cDay = c.kwhtotal; }

var generatedPower = cDay - pDay;
```

It works and runs, however it is inefficient.  It take far to long for the page to open when ran.  **Is there anything I can do to speed up this query?  All I need to do is subtract the `kwhtotal` of the last entry in the previous day from the `kwhtotal` of the last entry in the current day.**

Comment: Is changing the db an option? It may break normalization, but a table that stores these two values (only the current editions of them) would simplify things greatly.

Comment: Or create a materiazed view if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you combine the two queries into one, with the restriction s.recordTime >= prevStartD && s.recordTime <= currEndD and without the Take(1). This will mean only one trip to the database instead of two. Once you have the data set back you can query those results locally using the s.recordTime <= prevEndD condition to find your pDay value, then query again with the s.recordTime >= currStartD condition and look to the last record to get the cDay value.

Comment: I did move the two queries outside of the foreach they where in and stored the result in a list.  Then inside the query I used a query containing Max().  Now the performance is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousDay = (from s in db.PowerInverterHistorys
                   join u in db.PowerInverters on s.inverter_id equals u.id
                   where u.name == record && (s.recordTime >= prevStartD && s.recordTime <= prevEndD)
                   orderby s.recordTime descending
                   select new
                   {
                       s.recordTime,
                       s.kwhtotal
                   }).Take(1);
```

OrderBy is expensive operation for the DB if u have large dataset. Use Max() or Min() instead that will give u corresponding first row all the time.
THis should also apply to your "CurrentDay" query.